# Android "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES"

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting this error in Gradle with an Android project:

> Android "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES" [Solved-New]

I've read these questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987150/install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error-in-eclipse), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282169/installation-error-install-parse-failed-no-certificates)) but none of them solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to add to the body of knowledge here. We do not post amalgamated question-answers, however, so I have tried to separate the two. The above question now is rather thin, so if you can expand on it in any fashion, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Finally I find the solution.

**In my case The solution is `gradle` plugin version!** I'm using android studio ver 2.3.0-rc1 and gradle plugin (root `build.gradle`) with the same version, the release file could not install due to `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` failure, so I change the version of `gradle` plugin to `2.2.3` and make a new release again and the failure solved. I hope my solution help other guys with the same issue.

**Conclusion:**
root `build.gradle` file:

Replace:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:[any unstable version like 2.3.0-rc1]'
```

To:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed things for me, out of curiosity, how did you debug that? For me it would have been a big jump from no certs to gradle version.

Comment: @curriegrr It's undebuggable! I just tried everything I thought and finally the last one worked for me.

Comment: In my case the problem was because I generated a signed apk with version 2 of version signature V2(Full APK Signature). Changing to V1 solved my problem

Comment: @halfer, you're my saviour!

Comment: @rocknow: not my work, but cool! It was posted originally by the asker AlirezaXX, and I merely moved it to the answer box.

Comment: @SamiIssa, how can you change back to v1 signing ? 
Me too i need to switch back from v2 to v1... help!