# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS] when I tried adb install

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

The apk does not appear under menu or settings->apps->manage apps, but when I tried to install it using adb install I got this error  [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]. By the way I have already installed same apk on my other emulator which I already deleted. How could I fix this?

Comment: Still it doesn't solve my problem. The best way is to uninstall my app under settings->app->manage app but my problem is, the package is not showing here so how could I uninstall it? I also tried adb uninstall it just return 'failure'

Comment: What device are you using? If it's a tablet running latest Android version, then the problem might be that the application is not installed for *that* particular user but is installed for other users on the device, so you have to uninstall it for all. Also, note that you might have another application with the exact same package name already installed.

Comment: I have already deleted my other device without uninstalling the package there I think that causes my problem in installing that I could not install in my new device.

Comment: I guess you are installing a system app with a different certificate. Under this circumstance, you need root your device first, then delete your app before you installs.

Answer (score 19):

try :

```
adb install -r <your_apk>
```

Comment: It returns Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: I have already deleted my other device without uninstalling the package there I think that causes my problem in installing that I could not install in my new device.

Comment: @fulgen If it is reporting that error, it sounds like the app is already installed.  If you have more than one device connected, you may have already installed a different version of the app on the other device.

Comment: `adb uninstall -k $pkg` will preserve user's data for later `adb install  $pkg`. But `adb install -r $pkg` is way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be sure, try uninstalling the app with this command:

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

Comment: I tried it, it returns 'FAILURE'

Comment: have you tried to install it with the -r option: `adb install -r <your_apk>`

Comment: It returns Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: the certificates don't match.  You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786341/install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-on-adb-install

Comment: I have already deleted my other device without uninstalling the package there I think that causes my problem in installing that I could not install in my new device.

Comment: have you made sure to untick 'snapshot' on your device config?

Comment: did you mean to uncheck the snapshot when creating new device in avd manager..?