# ADB Install a signed APK over an unsigned APK that failed to install in the first place

Tags: android, adb, apk

I am attempting to sideload an APK with ADB. When I downloaded it, it was unsigned, but I attempted to install it, unknowingly, and it failed since it was unsigned. I signed it manually and verified that it was signed correctly, but when I go to install it with `adb install -r <path to signed apk>`, I get the following error:

`Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]`

So I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786341/install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-on-adb-install) that said to uninstall the old application that was unsigned, but I can't find the application on my device or anywhere in adb, so how am I supposed to uninstall the unsigned APK that failed to install in the first place? Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall you must know the package name of the application, Not the file name.
Usage Example:  `adb uninstall com.google.android.youtube`  (uninstalls youtube)

Comment: OK. Is there any way I can determine a package's name by looking at its contents? Edit: found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289149/read-the-package-name-of-an-android-apk) which got the package name. Thanks for the help!