# Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES. not able to install any application in a particular device

Tags: android

I am not able to install any application from android studio in to my specific device ,showing Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES.

Comment: this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786341/install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-on-adb-install

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal/3185824