# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES ANT build android

Tags: android, ant

We have a android project which we usually build with ant. When we tried to build the app in a different android device it gives us an `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES.`

After looking into various other questions posted in stackoverflow such as:
 [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES when install app for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157144/install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-when-install-app-for-the-first-ti)

I had tried to manually uninstall the app and then do the ant build. Even though it gives the same error.
Can anybody help with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157144/install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-when-install-app-for-the-first-ti?lq=1 might help

Comment: There's no information provided here that would make this question other than a duplicate of the listed one.  And did you try checking for double-signing as suggested in one of the answers there?  You are going to need to actively investigate this if you do not want it closed as a duplicate.

Comment: This question is already being answered on http://stackoverflow.com/a/3185824/1073780

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with INSTALL\_PARSE\_FAILED\_INCONSISTENT\_CERTIFICATES without uninstallation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal)