# Can't upgrade Android app (INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES)

Tags: android, certificate

I'm facing a huge problem here which is driving me crazy, I've made an Android app and now I want to publish the version 2 of it, but when I try to upgrade it I get the "Package file was not signed correctly" error. I was reading lots of forums and realize that this problem has lots of alternative solutions, but none of them is solving my problem. I've read people saying that should use the JDK6 instead of JDK7 (which I'm doing), others posted that adding an empty file, or modifying one, solved the problem, but not in my case. 
When I tried to install the app using adb I got this error: "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES" (already checked [this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal) post, and always used the production key, and the PC was the same, also tried using a different PC with a copy of the original debug.keystore, but didn't worked), and when I looked into the logcat didn't see any error/failure, actually I saw this on the logcat:

**I/ActivityManager( 1227): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/MYAPK.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity }**

....

**I/ActivityManager( 1227): Starting activity: Intent { dat=file:///sdcard/MYAPK.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) }**
W/Process ( 1227): Unable to open /proc/4002/status
**W/InstallAppProgress( 7636): Replacing package:com.MYCOMPANY.APP.activities**
....

V/WindowManager( 1227): Dsptch > Window{44b22a78 com.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress paused=false}

I/KeyInputQueue( 1227): Input event
V/WindowManager( 1227): Dsptch > Window{44b22a78 com.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress paused=false}
**I/InstallAppProgress( 7636): Finished installing com.MYCOMPANY.APP.activities**
In the middle of this lines, didn't see any error/failure.
So, considering that in the logcat there is no error and it says "Finished installing com.MYCOMPANY.APP.activities" I would think that the app should be installed, of course is not, so I don't know else can I do, does anybody have a clue about this problem?
BTW, I've installed the apk in my phone and with the LogCollector saw the same error.

Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved, changing the DATABASE_VERSION did the trick: I didn't changed the DB at all, but changing the version, with the onUpgrade method totally empty, was the solution. If any of you have this same problem, I want to recommend also [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/technical-help/JzAgJ414CQc), because it has another possible solutions to the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

did you changed the manifest file?
you need to change it to something like this example:
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1"