# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES after building project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I had an android project in NetBeans(using NBAndroid) - apk installed successfully every time, then, I switched to Eclipse, export the .apk, and tried to install it on an emulator.

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install MyApkName.apk
```

and it says

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

In LogCat appeared that line

```
03-11 10:55:00.710: E/PackageParser(77): Package com.package.name has no certificates at entry res/layout/chatrow.xml; ignoring!
```

Comment: It seems that many cases of this error are related to JDK1.7.  I had this error, and it was resolved as soon as JDK1.7 was replaced with JDK1.6

Answer (score 4):

Found it! I was having this problem with 'ant' and it was due to this CAUTION mentioned in the  documentation:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp
>
> Caution: As of JDK 7, the default signing algorithim has changed, requiring you to specify the signature and digest algorithims (-sigalg and -digestalg) when you sign an APK.

I have JDK 7, but it is probably the same issue. In my Ant log, I used -v for verbose and it showed

```
$ ant -Dadb.device.arg=-d -v release install
[signjar] Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\jarsigner.exe' with arguments:
[signjar] '-keystore'
[signjar] 'C:\cygwin\home\Chloe\pairfinder\release.keystore'
[signjar] '-signedjar'
[signjar] 'C:\cygwin\home\Chloe\pairfinder\bin\PairFinder-release-unaligned.apk'
[signjar] 'C:\cygwin\home\Chloe\pairfinder\bin\PairFinder-release-unsigned.apk'
[signjar] 'mykey'
 [exec]     pkg: /data/local/tmp/PairFinder-release.apk
 [exec] Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

I signed the JAR manually and zipaligned it, but it gave a slightly different error:

```
$ "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore release.keystore -signedjar bin/PairFinder-release-unaligned.apk bin/PairFinder-release-unsigned.apk mykey
$ zipalign -v -f 4 bin/PairFinder-release-unaligned.apk bin/PairFinder-release.apk
$ adb -d install -r bin/PairFinder-release.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/PairFinder-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
641 KB/s (52620 bytes in 0.080s)
```

I found that answered here.

[How to deal with INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES without uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal)

I only needed to uninstall it and then it worked!

```
$ adb -d uninstall com.kizbit.pairfinder
Success
$ adb -d install -r bin/PairFinder-release.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/PairFinder-release.apk
Success
641 KB/s (52620 bytes in 0.080s)
```

Now I only need modify the build.xml to use those options when signing!

Answer (score 0):

Try importing project rather than application(.apk) file to eclipse and then try running it.