# install fails on emulator due to inconsiatant certificates

Tags: android, launcher

I have been doing some changes into the default ICS launcher2 . When I install it on a device it works fine. But when i try to install on emulator it gives me following error

```
 Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
```

I know that it happens because of the conflict between certificate of previously installed laucher on the emulator & the one i am trying to install. I also changed the package name & tried.That also works on device but not emulator.
Thank you.

Comment: duplicate of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal).

Comment: I saw that link before . dint help a lot

Comment: and how can i get the keystore file of default launcher  if I am to sign it with the same key