# How to create an APK that returns multiple signatures from getPackageInfo(<apk>, GET_SIGNATURES)?

Tags: java, android, security, android-source

I am researching Android security and have identified a current application that makes use of the deprecated `getPackageInfo(<apk>, GET_SIGNATURES)`. To fully understand how this application is using this deprecated function I wish to create a proof-of-concept APK that results in multiple signatures being returned.

So far I have created a basic APK in Android Studio, created a CA certificate and a leaf certificate signed by my CA certificate. I then package both these into a PKCS12 file and then convert that to a Java Keystore. I then use the tool apksigner to sign my APK with this Java Keystore and install the signed app. I then verify that both certs are associated with the installed apk by pulling it off the phone and using `keytool -printcert -jarfile poc.apk`. This shows both certificates (CA and leaf) listed.

However, when running `getPackageInfo(<apk>, GET_SIGNATURES)` on my proof of concept APK only one result is returned? Why is this? What am I missing to get multiple signatures returned?

I have looked at the Android documentation for when the deprecated `GET_SIGNATURES` is passed to `getPackageInfo` but it is not very clear what the expected result should be. I am basing my expectation that a signature for each cert in the chain is returned based on this presentation: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Forristal-Android-FakeID-Vulnerability-Walkthrough.pdf.

This stackoverflow post states that the user had app installed on his phone from Verizon that had multiple signatures: [Why is the PackageInfo.signatures field an array, and when would there be anything other than one value here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618281/why-is-the-packageinfo-signatures-field-an-array-and-when-would-there-be-anythi). Likewise, the AOSP code has code to account for multiple signatures in multiple places.

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of: https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning and [GET_SIGNATURES is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52898066/295004)

Comment: Yep, I looked at the Android documentation a lot to try and work out how multiple signatures could be returned but I didn't find anything that helped explicitly. It was very useful in understanding how signing works though which helped building up the proof of concept.

I have also looked at that stackoverflow post and I have code very similar to it to print the signatures in my proof of concept app.