# Google Play services out of date. Requires 3025100 but found 2012110

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-maps-v2, google-play-services

I'm using the Google maps v2 in my app and am debugging it in the emulator. Since the update on the 26th Feb I now get this error message

```
Google Play services out of date. Requires 3025100 but found 2012110
```

I now wonder if anyone has the updated files necessary to run google play services rev 5 in the emulator? I've tried to run the app with rev 4 of Google play services, but the emulator is not having it and asks for me to update Google play services. Does anyone have any other ideas perhaps?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you updated with revision 5?

Comment: Development of Maps V2 apps is not supported on the emulator at this time.

Comment: @Mitesh Yes, I updated to revision 5 with the SDK. I have also tried to downgrade back to rev 4, but the emulator is then telling me that Google play services need to be updated. I guess I just need the `vending.apk` and `gms.apk` for the updated play services. But I can't seem to get hold of them.

Comment: @CommonsWare Not officially no, but you just need to install the play services manually and it does. See [this tutorial](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/2012/12/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/)

Comment: And that is called "software piracy".

Comment: Well I'm actually getting this on a real device, just after I set up a clean enviroment on a new laptop with a project that was working ok previously, any ideas as to what can be happening? EDIT: I just found out that my device was to blame. It was actually a recently reset galaxy tab, which still had the old Android Market in it.

Comment: @Linn, did you succeed at getting updated to 3025100?

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert found the files! :D See answer

Comment: @Linn [How to set up a fast emulator for Android on Linux?](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20130912/how-to-set-up-a-fast-emulator-for-android-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the files I needed in the end, [gms](http://uploaded.net/file/bnzl1si4) and [vending](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=9390135922294521859)

Comment: Hi. i got an error wile executing this "adb install -r gms.apk"
it says "inconsistent certivicates" can u help me?

Comment: @Alfa Hmm.. nothing I've ever come across unfortunately. But I found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3185824/1372400). It might help?

Answer (score 0):

After the updateion of ADT 22.0.1 and new Android Private Libraries, the google map service was giving some or the error and app crashes off.
So i found the solution finally and it worked for me.

Just install the google play service lib and than go to the google-play-service/libproject/google-play-services_lib from the link below :-

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ok76ep7lmav0qf/9XVlv61D2b

than import that into your workspace .
Clean your project where you want to use gogole-play-services-lib than build it agian and go to the Project > Properties > Java BuildPath > select "Android Private Libraries, android Dependencies, google-play-service"

in Properties itself go to Android and than choose any of the version and than choose add and select google-play-service-lib and than press apply and finally OK.

At last go to the Project > Android Tools > Android Support Libraries . Accept the license and after installing than run your project.

It will Work Fine.

Hope this Will Help You.