# How to update Google Play Services through adb?

Tags: android, google-maps, adb, google-play-services

I have implemented an application with fresh Google Maps in time when device I've tested it on uses outdated one. It works fine while I used to build apk on Eclipse with fresh Google Play Services as dependency library project (as described there [Google Play services out of date. Requires 3025100 but found 2012110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156301/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-3025100-but-found-2012110)). But when I have built apk with **Android.mk** with **google-play-services.jar** as *LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES* builded by the script application is crashed and **GooglePlayServicesUtil** throws an error:

```
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 4452000 but found 4034530
```

As it's expected the following statement is true:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED
```

Is it possible to update Google Play Services on the devices with **adb** (it's unable to connect the device to Internet dirrectly)? Or maybe there is another suitable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easy. You have to simple install **Google Play Services.apk** which (version 4.4.52) is presented here: [[APK Compendium] Google Play Services 4.4.52 for All Densities, and the Rest of This Week’s Updates](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/apk-compendium-google-play-services-4-4-52-for-all-densities-and-the-rest-of-this-weeks-updates/).

I have `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` now while I'm trying to inflate maps layout xml but this issue is out off topic.