# Android Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: java, android, installation, apk

I read all previous threads related to this matter but I could not solve my problem. Hence I post it here. My application has a text to pdf converter and I used iText for it. When I tried to install the application to the device the console says,
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES. 
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!

In logcat it says,
01-15 14:30:09.019: E/PackageParser(2454): Package com.example.example has no certificates at entry res/layout/activity_main.xml; ignoring!

I'm using JDK 1.6 and android Android 4.4. I uninstalled previous .apk and clean and build the project.

EDIT: As a solution for this problem, I tried to sing the application using eclipse. But after gave the keystore and alias it is gave error as "duplicate files at the same path inside the apk". I checked my lib folder if there is any duplicate jars and cleaned and rebuilt it. But still I cannot export signed apk.

As far as I can understand issues for above both cases that jars may be has file same as in my application. But I don't know hot to solve this. Any suggestion would be welcome to get rid of this problem.

Comment: are you using jar signer to sign apk? if not please reply

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay No, I'm not

Comment: i gave my answer please follow...hope it will work for you!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3185824/1073780 has answer for your question