# Error while Installing .apk file through adb

Tags: android, adb, android-install-apk

I am trying to install an apk file on my Android device using ADB with the following command:

```
E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>adb install -r WebserviceA
ctivity.apk
```

But I get this error message:

```
158 KB/s (225399 bytes in 1.391s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/WebserviceActivity.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with INSTALL\_PARSE\_FAILED\_INCONSISTENT\_CERTIFICATES without uninstallation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal)

Answer (score 0):

Before put your question in stackoverflow just do some googling i'm sure you get something very useful.

Anyways,

try like this

uninstall the existing .apk

and then

re-install the new .apk

Answer (score 0):

Googling your error message can be very succesfull:

> It means the new copy of your application (on your development
>   machine) was signed with a different signing key than the old copy of
>   your application (installed on the device/emulator). For example, if
>   this is a device, you might have put the old copy on from a different
>   development machine (e.g., some other developer's machine). Or, the
>   old one is signed with your production key and the new one is signed
>   with your debug key.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3185824/1683141

So you need to make sure your application is signed with same key as the currently installed application. Note that a debug key is different from a regular key.

If you do not have your old signing key anymore, then you should remove your old application first.

Comment: Thank you. I get this error while installing the app on to the same emulator and haven't signed it with any other keys.

Comment: I can only tell you the meaning of the error message, and that is described above. Sorry I can't help you any further.