# Error When Trying To Run A Cordova Application On An Android Device

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to run a cordova application on my Android phone using the command 'cordova run'. Everytime I run this with my phone plugged in to my computer I get the following error:

Installing app on device...

```
/Users/Rubio/Projects/beaconDemo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device:  pkg: /data/local/tmp/CordovaApp-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/Rubio/Projects/beaconDemo/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

How can i get around this issue?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means the new copy of your application (on your development machine) was signed with a different signing key than the old copy of your application (installed on the device/emulator). For example, if this is a device, you might have put the old copy on from a different development machine (e.g., some other developer's machine). Or, the old one is signed with your production key and the new one is signed with your debug key.
Source : [How to deal with INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES without uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal)