# Android Studio Inconsistent Certificates after system restore

Tags: android, android-studio

I did a system restore and Android Studio has had a number of issues ever since. The latest one is telling me `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]` when I go to run my app. Saying I need to uninstall the previous app. Is there any way around this?

This is the first time I've faced this idea of signing, despite changing computers and switching between Eclipse and Android Studio numerous times. I really don't want to uninstall the app because it contains a lot of useful data on it.

Is there a signing file located somewhere in the project's folder? I have an older version of my project folder from before all of this.

Answer (score 1):

The debug key that is used for signing your apk is not stored in the project folder, but in `~/.android/debug.keystore`. If you can't find the old keystore, you'll need to reinstall your app.

See also the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3185824/298468