# Including GCM to project results in certificate error

Tags: android, gradle, certificate, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

All that I did was follow the exact tutorial as mentioned on the Google Developers page to include GCM.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Added all needed permissions at the manifest, gradle dependencies at app level and module level.

I even uninstalled the app, did a gradlew clean, re-build. Nothing works out.
I get the same error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error.

When I revert back the changes, everything gets back to normal, I don't get any packaging or certificate error. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185444/how-to-deal-with-install-parse-failed-inconsistent-certificates-without-uninstal?lq=1

Comment: Already checked on that.. tried all, it doesn't work. I even used a different LG Nexus 5 to see if the issue persists. It does..

Comment: Could you include the manifest in the question?