# Adb install failed

Tags: android, adb

I'am developing an android app. before this morning everythings ok when i click 'run' in Android Studio, the IDE will compile my codes and install apk to my devices automatically.but now device will disconnect automatically when IDE install apk, so i try to install apk manually,i got same result，like this:

[image]

**My Envirement**
OS:Ubuntu 16.04
Android Studio: Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-65-generic
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.4-5871666

Is anyone got same error like me?
Thanks you.

Comment: try unistalling the app completely from your device and try again

Comment: god, i solved by doing this: adb kill-server;adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to install a debug app with adb. Debug APK file is signed with debug Keystore and wont be installed with adb.
You need to sign your app. go to link below, generate a Keystore and build  your APK file with that Keystore file.
[guide to sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Don't lose your Keystore file and passwords and try to protect it because you will need it later for updates.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i solved my problem by doing this: adb kill-server;adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes installed package meta info resides in app install package which causes to show 'failed to install .apk.
simply run adb uninstall com.package command and try to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this issue after upgrading Android 3.6

I first tried everything listed on [Android error: Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Many of those suggestions are common and should be tried as well. I had to change cable in the past. reboot devices. uninstall applications. but nothing was working today.

I finally figured I needed to update the SDK toolkits

[image]

it is now working fine