# Android apk does not install? Where can I check the logs for this? No reason is given

Tags: android

I'm clicking on apk file and it prompts for install but quickly stops without indicating if it was installed or not or what the issue is. How can I see why it is not installed? Where is the log for this kind of information?

Comment: you can check the Logcat messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/android-what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error this might be a reason!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591006/1778421

Answer (score 10):

Can you connect your device to your machine via usb?  You should be able to go to a prompt and do:

```
    adb install <apk_name>.apk
```

and see the error if the uninstall in unsuccessful.  This is assuming `adb` is in your path.  It's normally located in your `android_install_directory/platform-tools/`