# Installation fails after upgrading to Android 7 Nougat on a Galaxy Tab S2

Tags: android, adb

After upgrading my tablet to Android 7 Nougat I can no more install mySample.apk with the command line:

```
adb install ./build/outputs/apk/mySample.apk
```

I can only get:

```
Failed to install ./build/outputs/apk/mySample.apk:
```

and with adb logs:

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

PS:
Now it works but I have to enable ADB over Wi-Fi with the commands:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.0.101:5555
```

as Brian said in [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)
...apparently it's no more possible to connect my device only by USB cable
.

Comment: Can you post adb logs

Comment: Is USB debugging still enabled?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591006/1778421