# How to execute an APK (Test cases) through ADB command?

Tags: java, android, adb, android-install-apk

I'm unable to get the detailed description of installation of an apk. I have tried adb install "filename.apk" it showing only success. Is there any way to get full log file while installing or executing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android apk does not install? Where can I check the logs for this? No reason is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405751/android-apk-does-not-install-where-can-i-check-the-logs-for-this-no-reason-is)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591006/1778421

Answer (score 0):

When running a UI test on the emulator or device the gradle builds two apk files, one for the app, and one for the testing code. Let’s build both the app and the testing app and install them.

First connect a device or an emulator, and type in the command line in the project folder:

```
./gradlew clean installDebug installDebugAndroidTest
```

This command will:

- clean the build folder
- compile and install the app on the device
- compile and install testing app on the device

Now for the fun part. Run the tests from command line:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class com.your.app.ExampleInstrumentedTest#checkButton com.your.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Let’s explain the above command first:

- “adb shell am instrument -w” runs all the UI tests
- “-e debug false” is because we don’t want to debug the testing
- “-e class com.your.app.ExampleInstrumentedTest#checkButton com.your.app.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner” this tells our app to run a specific test