# Android 12 cannot download

Tags: flutter, google-play, android-12

I have noticed that the people that cannot install my app all have Android 12 (since there are no installations with Android 12 in the statistics)

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there something extra you need to add?

Lastly, the APK has been installed on Android 12 in testing, but unable to install it from Google Play

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android apk does not install? Where can I check the logs for this? No reason is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405751/android-apk-does-not-install-where-can-i-check-the-logs-for-this-no-reason-is)

Comment: Just a hint for future questions: Generic questions like these cannot be answered properly and will be a guessing game only. Without knowing your source, your dependencies etc. no one will be able to identify your problem. And even if you were to provide the full source, one can only do the same as in the linked question: Look for errors and debug - which is, honestly, your job. After you've found the error, you'll probably find a dozen questions on SO about it...

Comment: @maio290 like stated the APK can be downloaded and run on Android 12, just not from Google Play, so sadly it didn't answer my question.

And yes I know it is hard to get issues like this solved, but I didn't have anything to research on, so I thought that it didn't hurt to try here.

Comment: @NPovlsen what's your targetsdkversion of app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this migration guide helped

https://medium.com/tech-takeaways/migrating-my-app-to-android-12-7bafba3ed999