# ADB Push INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android, dictionary, sdk, adb

I am currently having a problem with my ZeniThink Android tablet with Jellybean, this is that all words I type in on every application underlines itself in red implying it is not in the dictionary. I searched on the internet and found two apk's to copy to system> app folder however one will not copy which I am to believe it is a common error and that to overcome it you should ADB push. The apk's I found are LatinIme.apk and LatinImeGoogle.apk, which is the one that will not copy. (Source: http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/coby-generation-3-technical/45920-predictive-spelling-dictionary-solved.html#post236467)

I understand nothing about ADB but have been following video tutorials on YouTube and have managed to connect my device to Android SDK using WiFi as I do not have a USB cable for my tablet. I tried to copy/install the apk. by using this code:

```
    adb install LatinImeGoogle.apk
```

However, I get this error:

```
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platform-tools>adb install LatinImeGoo
gle.apk 
9 KB/s (6160710 bytes in 663.958s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/LatinImeGoogle.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

As I know absolutely nothing about ADB or anything to do with developing, by reading posts on this website, I am really struggling to find a solution.

Please help me stop the horrible underlining of words!

Thanks in Advance,

James

Comment: You probably should not be trying to install random apk's of unknown provenance in your system partition!  Most likely they will not install as they have been pre-optimized for the specific phone they came from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is INSTALL\_PARSE\_FAILED\_NO\_CERTIFICATES error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error)

Answer (score 0):

i met this issue before, 
same code and ketstore compile the build(winxp&jdk1.6) and throw this error when installing;
When I try to change other pc and compile (win7&jdk7.0) and this issue cannot be happened;

I think you can try the same way or change the dev env