# android 'app not installed' error. how to debug?

Tags: android, installation

i have developed an app in eclipse, so today i made an apk (made the keystore and all that)

i put it on my website and downloaded it to my samsung GT7300 running 4.0.4 and it installs and runs fine.

now i just tried to install on my no name Chinese tablet running 4.2.2 and i get 'app not installed' every time.

i enabled unknown source of course, is there anything else i could have missed?

when i get the 'app not installed' message, there is no explanation of any kind. is there an installer log or something where i can find the problem?

if anyone would care to try install for me, its at 
http://www.2112design.com/fbmstools/ and the file is fbms_lmfd.apk

maybe i'm no supposed to post that, don't know

thanks for any help, this is driving me nuts!

by the way, i read this ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android) and non of those suggestions helped

i connected the debug cable to the device and it installs and runs fine through adb.

so i created a blank application and made an apk and put on my website, then download to tablet and it installs fine. so i guess there is something wrong with my real app, but the manifests are basically the same.

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

so i installed a logcat view on the tablet, and when i try install from the apk i get a couple of error messages

Package ..... has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml: ignoring

then

Installation error code: -103

Comment: fyi, `public static final int INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES = -103;` so you could probably also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914105/11509478)

Answer (score 5):

Install the apk using `adb install apkname.apk`. Adb shows the error that happened on the console.

Answer (score 2):

In my case using lollipop was that my app was installed on different user of the phone, so I had to enter to every user session and delete the app from each one.

Then after the complete removal from every user it was able to install again.

Answer (score 0):

try to plug your tablet on your computer and take a look at the logcat.

Even better, try to run your application through eclipse straight on the device, you should get info from console/logcat directly

Comment: but the app isn't running, its not installing at all. anyhow, i'll try

Comment: i just tired it with with the usb from eclipse and its fine. and its now installed (via eclipse adb) and it it runs fine. maybe something wrong in the keystore?

Comment: probably the keystore. Eclipse uses a generated debug keystore.
If you need to install on third device for debuging(not publishing) and you cannot attach it to eclipse(eg. send to a friend) try to sign your exported apk with the debug keystore.

Under windows you can find it on %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 0):

When we create android application, we specify min SDK and target SDK in manifest.xml file. Please check whether your Tablet falls within this range or not. The api level for your tablet is 17 (android 4.2.2)

Comment: i have android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="15"., i think so long as these are lower, it should work right?

Comment: Yes, I want to know that did you change the original apk file name? Also you can get the exact error by connecting tablet using eclipse adb and checking logcat output (install the apk file directly while tablet is connected in eclipse)

Comment: i created the apk from scratch and didn't change the name. i connected the USB and ran from eclipse and it runs fine, no errors. so still no closer. thanks.

Comment: No you didnt get me. I just want to say that you only connect device with eclipse for viewing logcat output but dont install it from eclipse. Install the apk downloaded on the tablet and while installing view logcat in in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

well, i can't say i know the exact problem, but i deleted all my old keystores, started over from export... in eclipse, created a new keystore and it worked.