# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error in debug build Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, build, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

I just included the GCM library in my project and run the debug build. It fails with the above error. 
In my build.gradle file, I already have the signing configurations as below

```
 signingConfigs {
    signing_config {
        storePassword "123456"
        keyAlias "debug"
        keyPassword "debug"
        storeFile file("${rootDir}/app.keystore")
    }
}
```

My build gradle looks like this.

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

signingConfigs {
    signing_config {
        storePassword "123456"
        keyAlias "debug"
        keyPassword "debug"
        storeFile file("${rootDir}/app.keystore")
    }
}


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.application.example"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode project.versionCode
    versionName project.versionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.signing_config
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
       bla bla bla -- all server config related stuff
    }

    release {
        signingConfig android.signingConfigs.signing_config
        applicationIdSuffix 
       bla bla bla -- all server config related stuff
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}

dependencies {
//many dependencies
}
```

I use the same config to sign for release builds which work perfectly fine.
Only on debug I get this error.
Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please include the output of `gradle build --stacktrace` in the question

Comment: Also post all of your `build.gradle` need to see how you assigned the signing config to the builds

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/android-what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error) would help.