# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES on Android L

Tags: android, sign, meta-inf

I've added an empty file to the `META-INF` of my **apk**, For `Android 4.3`, it was installed as usual, but when when i installed it on `Android 5.0.2`, it failed with `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: what is INSTALL\_PARSE\_FAILED\_NO\_CERTIFICATES error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/android-what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error)

Comment: Ideally you can not edit into apk file directly.

Comment: but it`s the "META-INF" directory,  if you add an empty file into it, there is no need to re-signed you apk.

Comment: @goonerDroid this question is different with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error. Please read words carefully and remove your post.

Answer (score 0):

Same error in my android project. The difference is that adding empty files naming like channel_ in META-INF folder in my project.

After adding above file, I have to use "zipalign" on apk file.

I have to build more than 100 apks (different in ), some of them can be installed on Android L, some others can't.