# How to make 'cordova run --release' use the signed apk

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

### Problem

I'm trying to install and test a release version of my app directly on my device using cordova.

Though I signed the apk, cordova tries to install the unsigned version to the device. How can I test the release version via cordova?

### Details

When running

```
cordova run --release --buildConfig="build.json"
```

I get the following result:

```
[...]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 15.086 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/myProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
        C:/myProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release.apk
Using apk: C:/myProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
Error: Failed to install apk to device: pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-release-unsigned.apk

Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

Comment: What is your build engine ? ant or gradle ? anyway check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/4843212/1641556

Comment: I didn't specify that anywhere but my ``\platforms\android`` folder is filled with gradle files and folders. So I guess it's gradle is the default. How do I check it?

Comment: @devopsEMK I can't see how your link is helpful to my problem. The apk is signed correctly and I can upload it to Google Play without problems.

Comment: Please check this  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2914105/1641556

Answer (score 2):

[This issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10600) has been fixed but it's not released yet.
You can try the development version of cordova-android for now:
`cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android`