# Android Studio Signed APK App not installing

Tags: android, android-studio, signed-apk

I know there are other questions similar to this but I havent found a solution to my problem. Ive made sure that no previous installation of the app was already on my phone (testing on a galaxy s6), in Android Studio in the Build Variants tab I've switched the module to release (I also have a Firebase and MainlibProj module, should I switch them to release as well?) and when I try installing it this is what I get in logcat:

```
07-07 17:25:40.807 3506-3553/? W/PackageManager: Failed collect during installPackageLI
android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Package /data/app/vmdl13968685.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml
at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1127)
at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1077)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:14349)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$2600(PackageManagerService.java:333)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$8.run(PackageManagerService.java:11894)at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I also get a:

```
InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -103
```

That is not the full stack trace, just what is printed when I'm notified: app not installed.

Just in case, I have Play Games Plugin for Unity in my app, dont know if that may potentially be causing the error.

Comment: are you using signature v2 ?

Comment: yup, when I click generate signed apk I have v2 checked for full apk signature.

Comment: fyi, `public static final int INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES = -103;` so you could probably also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914105/11509478)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I appear to have solved the problem.

When I generate a signed APK I need to check off both V1 and V2. Previously I only had V2 checked off, not entirely sure why checking V1 also, fixed it.

Comment: Using V1 and V2 probably worked because the target OS was pre-7.0. See https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/