# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES in eclipse java photon

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have one old project that runs only in eclipse hence i have downloaded eclipse java photon and configured the ADT tools into it. I have mappped the Android sdk provided by studio with it and tried to run the app into the device but each time i run this app i am getting following error

```
 Installing SLTL.apk...
 Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
 Please check logcat output for more details.
 Launch canceled!
```

when i checked the logcat i am getting following error

```
/com.android.defcontainer D/DefContainer: Copying /data/local/tmp/SLTL.apk to base.apk
10-02 14:17:52.233 1957-1990/system_process W/PackageManager: Failed collect during installPackageLI
    android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl871259287.tmp/base.apk
        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1130)
        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1057)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:12196)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap25(PackageManagerService.java)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$9.run(PackageManagerService.java:10156)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:201)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:106)
        at java.util.jar.StrictJarFile.<init>(StrictJarFile.java:66)
        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1072)
        at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:1057) 
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:12196) 
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-wrap25(PackageManagerService.java) 
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$9.run(PackageManagerService.java:10156) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

My system configuration is windows 10 and using java 1.8 as compiler with java 1.8 jre , i tried to search lot many threads and blogs but could not find the solution

I have tried editing the `Android manifest` file too but no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is INSTALL\_PARSE\_FAILED\_NO\_CERTIFICATES error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error)

Comment: @Arty i have tried this too but its not solving my problem