# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES Error on Android Studio

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to run a simple app on my android phone, using Android Studio, and always get this error message:

Session 'app': Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES Retry

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `debug` build:

In Android Studio, open the **Build Variants** window  and set the **Active Build Variant** to `debug` for your modules.

If you are trying to run the `release` build, you need to set up the signing configuration (V1 or V2) correctly.