# i am getting an error trying to run Appium test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

running the following code:

```java
    public static void opencalculator() throws MalformedURLException  {

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "android x86");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");

        URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4722/wd/hub");

        driver =new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url, cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

gives me this error :

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in PATH. Please set the ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variables to the correct Android SDK root directory path.
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

considering that i changed the path many as per the message above

this is the error appearing now after modifying the paths

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install -r C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb: failed to install C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl541246303.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/CERT.SF has invalid digest for javax/annotation/meta/Exclusive.java in /data/app/vmdl541246303.tmp/base.apk]'; Code: '1' Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'WAER', ip: '192.168.178.83', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.5' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install -r C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb: failed to install C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl541246303.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/CERT.SF has invalid digest for javax/annotation/meta/Exclusive.java in /data/app/vmdl541246303.tmp/base.apk]'; Code: '1' at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9) at asyncHandler (C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37) Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'WAER', ip: '192.168.178.83', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.5' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208) at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217) at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552) at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41) at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1) at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213) at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131) at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37) at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:88) at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:98) at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:94) at appiumtest.calculatortest.opencalculator(calculatortest.java:47) at appiumtest.calculatortest.main(calculatortest.java:26) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186) ... 15 more Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install -r C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb: failed to install C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl541246303.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/CERT.SF has invalid digest for javax/annotation/meta/Exclusive.java in /data/app/vmdl541246303.tmp/base.apk]'; Code: '1' Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'WAER', ip: '192.168.178.83', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.5' Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install -r C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb: failed to install C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl541246303.tmp/base.apk: META-INF/CERT.SF has invalid digest for javax/annotation/meta/Exclusive.java in /data/app/vmdl541246303.tmp/base.apk]'; Code: '1' at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9) at asyncHandler (C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126) at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958) at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127) at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502) at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488) at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150) at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128) ... 20 more

Comment: The error says it all. The server can't run `adb.exe` because the path to the program `adb` is probably missing in the PATH variable.

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install -r C:\\Users\\ahmed\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\a

Comment: Can you put the complete error from the comment section in the question? And you may also want to check the [android adb documention](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) for all adb commands and options.

Comment: i have added the error above

Comment: Looks like your apk is not correctly signed. Have a look at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914105/3559908). Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Java and Android SDK environment variables before running your tests