# Android Studio Wear Os application can't be installed INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: java, android-studio, wear-os, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I'm new in the the magic world of Android Studio. I'm trying to develop a simple Wear Os application to scan the near Bluetooth devices.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.firstapp.testble;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>ERRORRE");
        }else{
            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

            // Enables Always-on
            setAmbientEnabled();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.i("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.firstapp.testble">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I'm trying to debug the application in my Fossil SmartWatch uploading the APK to the device, i receive the following error:

```
Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
Timed out waiting for process (com.firstapp.testble) to appear on fossil-garrett_hr-127.0.0.1:4444.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\marac\AndroidStudioProjects\TestBLE\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
APK signature verification failed.
```

With other simple application I don't have this kind of problem.
Here what I already tryed:

1. Build> Generate Singned Bundle / APK
2. Clean Project and Rebuild Project
3. File > Invalidate Cache / Restart
4. Disconnect and reconnect the smartwatch
5. Re-Install Android Studio

I don't understand why I have this problem and why I have it only with this project. Can you help me to solve?

Thanks,
Mara

Comment: Did you resolve this? I seem to be able to deploy to my phone through usb when running in debug mode. I had previously been able to do the same over wifi and wearos, but now am getting the same error you are.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver  is not support in WearOS
I've resolved using this tutorial: https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-2-47a3cdaade07

Answer (score 0):

If you have signed your apk, you might consider install the release build instead of the debug build that you are trying to install.

From the following log, I can see that you are trying to install the debug build.

```
[0] 'C:\Users\marac\AndroidStudioProjects\TestBLE\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
```

The release apk can be found under `\Users\marac\AndroidStudioProjects\TestBLE\app\build\outputs\apk\release` folder.

Comment: The problem is that I need to test my application in the debug mode. I tried to make the operation of Build> Generate Singned Bundle / APK butnothig works. 
The code compile correctly, the problem is only when I try to upload the apk to my SmartWatch. 
Is there somthing that I dont undestand?

Comment: I see. Can you please check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62157265/3145960

Comment: Did you resolve this? I don't have any signingConfigs in my gradle.