# Failed to collect certificates from...? After trying to install flutter apk

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run apk file on the device using `flutter install`. The following error displays

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install F:\...\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES:Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl619719557.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array]
Install failed
```

How can I collect certificates?

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same error and I solved it by adding signing config in `app/build.gradle`
the code looks like below for debug mode:

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and able to fix it in this way:

1. uninstall the old application
2. clean the project
3. run and reinstall it again

if this not works, try signing the apk.