# Why Flutter blue plus is not working on release mode?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk, release

I want to run app on release mode but I got this output in my terminal:

[image: output]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error did you check this question

Answer (score 1):

I found that `M2103K19G` is Xiaomi Redmi Note 10.

For `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` error, Check this out: [What is INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914105/what-is-install-parse-failed-no-certificates-error)

I guess you didn't set the signing key, alias, and their passwords.